# ADP remote debugging two devices at the same time

Tags: android, debugging

is it possible to debug two android device parallells? ( nexus 7, galaxy s3 )
I got both devices usb plugged, they both work one-by-one but not together.

about:inspect only shows one device and desktop pages

another side question, is it possible to remote debug iPhone 5 other than Safari? 
Or this is another thing that apple don't let to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**That's not possible..**

As we can have only one process running for our application at a time in ADB and that will connect to only one device at a time.

Comment: too bad, thanks anyway.. what about chrome canary for the other device? letm e try this -- tried it, not working :3

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. ADB will only connect to one source at once.

My best suggestion is two debug with 2 host machines simultaneously. Presumably you have a client/server style application?